# How to have shared layout for specific page?

Tags: sxa, presentation

I am trying to achieve the shared layout for all the languages of the item. Basically, I have a project where a multiple pages are already made, and for 8 languages. Now I need to change every page (they are basically product pages) with that same template to a newer design with a newer components.

Is there any way to make this achievable in not a long time (Basically changing every single page of a product in every single language)? I have heard about the shared layout but how to achieve that in SXA? Also, is it good that to make a new Page Design only for those pages? The problem there is that I need to change the data sources because I think every page will then have the same items with that same data source, and that is not good option if you think about it.

Comment: The quickest option you have would be to create an SPE script to copy the final layout into the shared layout for those pages and clear out the final layout field. Then you are shared going forward.

Comment: @RichardSeal Okay than. I also think that is going to be the best solution here

Comment: A longer-term solution might be to change the way your product pages work. I normally don't have a page per product and use wildcard items to programmatically get the data based on the URL. Then you only have a single page to maintain. Very helpful when you have lots of products